# ASP.NET glimse not quoting varchar field

Tags: asp.net, entity, glimpse

In this case the column is the primary key and perhaps its making an assumption that this key will be numeric, but this is not the case

[image]

In this example, if I take the sql and try to run it in sql manager or similar it will fail as the two references to AU should be 'AU'

Comment: What data type are those params?

Comment: varchar(2) and the primary key

Comment: Looking into this, what is the `DbType` of the param?

Comment: The type shown by glimpse is AnsiString

Comment: Being tracked in https://github.com/Glimpse/Glimpse/issues/812

Comment: This has been fixed (see 812) and is set to go out with the next release.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed in 
https://github.com/Glimpse/Glimpse/issues/812

Available in next release